# How to get all data from Python Requests response when data volume is large?

Tags: python, json, python-requests, max, character

I am using Python 3.7.6 and the "requests" (v2.22.0) module to obtain some gaming data from a public game API. I've had no problems obtaining small amounts of data but have hit an issue with large data volumes.

Using the following URL in a browser: https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/19683 ,
I get a nice JSON list in the browser showing the order book for an in-game commodity. It's a rather long list.

When attempting to capture the data using Python and the requests module, the retrieved data is truncated. It appears that requests is not returning the entire data set.

Code used:

```
import json
import requests
URL = 'https://api.guildwars2.com/v2/commerce/listings/19683'
response = requests.get(url=URL, params=None)
response.status_code
response.headers
response.content
response.text
response.json()
jsonApiData = response.json()
```

When I inspect the data from the `response.content` and `response.text` lines, it's obvious that data have been truncated. It's very visible when viewing the json object from `response.json`.  From copying the data from the browser into Atom and comparing the character counts with `response.json`, it looks like the request response was not fully parsed or truncated.

I've looked in the requests docs (https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) for a maximum character count and found no limitations.

I'm still fairly new with JSON and requests but have not run into things like this even when downloading 100's of MB of data as images from other API's.

Has anyone dealt with a situation like this? How can I retrieve the entire dataset?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've just tried something different to isolate the issue: I snipped the text from the website URL where the full data set is presented and saved it as a json file. When I try to read the file using  `json.load()` the read file is also truncated. When I cut out a big chunk of data and resave, all of the remaining data are read so it looks to be some limitation of requests or python and requests.

Comment: Further testing... I found a nifty Visual Studio Extension called "Rest Client" that allows me to directly run the GET query - and voila, the entire dataset is returned. With this, I got the idea of running the query in plain old Python on the command line and guess what, it also returns the entire data set. It seems the problem is Visual Studio Code. I did not post that I was using VSCode in the original post. Now hunting the forums for this.

Answer (score 0):

The data could have been truncated in atom.

I'd say count the dictionary keys. This would give you a better idea of the actual data is being truncated.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the idea... the data are already truncated before I paste into Atom. The 'requests' package is not getting all of the data as noted when I inspect the data via `response.json`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the ipython interactive buffer in VS Code. It has a max character limit that I was surpassing. Funny thing is that I since I do all of my coding and debugging in VSCode, the buffer issue was affecting both sides - coding and debugging, making it look like the data itself was affected.

Once I open the JSON in other tools, I can see the full data set. Guess I should get out of VSCode every now and then lolz.

I may post a feature request in Microsoft's GIT for this. There should be a visual indicator showing that data is being hidden. (Much like the ellipses in Pandas Dataframes.) As it is, the data is just cut and posted with a hard transition.
[image]