# Response cut short in VSCode (Python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, scripting

I have a Python script that reaches out to an API and generates a large dataset. For some reason, VSCode only displays part of the data in the response. I found the below

[How to get all data from Python Requests response when data volume is large?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192068/how-to-get-all-data-from-python-requests-response-when-data-volume-is-large)

Is there anything I can do to avoid this in VSCode?

Thank you

Comment: you could output your data to a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you have a look at

[Visual Studio Code - Python - List Index Limit Max 300 - Debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324745/visual-studio-code-python-list-index-limit-max-300-debugger)

and

[VS Code's debug console cannot display complete data.](https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/582)

I guess you mean you can not inspect the full data in the `VARIABLES` panel when you debugging your code, and can not print the full data in the `PYTHON DEBUG CONSOLE` while it can print the full data out of debugging. Isn't it?

The reason you run across **'Too large to show contents. Max items to show: 300'** was because it was configured by the `debugpy` module:

[image]

And you can configure it with enter into this python file:

...\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_resolver.py

and configured `MAX_ITEMS_TO_HANDLE = 300` to other values.

And if you want the `PYTHON DEBUG CONSOLE` can print the full data, you need to add this in the launch.json file:

```
"env": {"PYTHONUNBUFFERED": "0" }
```

Comment: Where is the launch.json file?